# Cosmos SQL find items which has a string in array

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm trying to write a query in CosmosDB using SQL for the following scenario. Let say I have a collection with items as follows

```
{
   "resource": "abc",
   "region": "east",
   "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
}

{
   "resource": "def",
   "region": "east",
   "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"]
}

{
   "resource": "xyz",
   "region": "east",
   "tags": ["tag3"]
}
```

now I want to write a query that return all items that has a string "tag1" in tags property (I want to get/project all the properties in that item)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [`ARRAY_CONTAINS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-array-contains) system function for that. So your query would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Root r where ARRAY_CONTAINS(r.tags, "tag1")
```

and this would give a result like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "cd385b65c6b14b07eb157b72485b1260",
        "resource": "abc",
        "region": "east",
        "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2"
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": "bb77e9ad1950467390cbc5ffac33cac3",
        "resource": "def",
        "region": "east",
        "tags": [
            "tag1",
            "tag2"
        ],
    }
]
```